# Invert functionality of LoginView

Tags: asp.net, login-control, loginview

Is it possible to invert the functionality of the LoginView in ASP.NET?

I want exclude some content for a certain role and the way I see it you use the LoginView to show extra content on the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create views for individual role by editing `RoleGroups` property.

Comment: Yes, but that means adding every group created to it apart from the one I want to exclude. Isn't there a way to hide one role instead of creating views for every other role? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Set Visible property for those UI element you don't wish to show.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that but I hoped there would be a nicer way to go about. Thanks for the reply!